# How to post value to multi php page?

Tags: php, post

the input button is in index.php

```
<form method="post" action="1.php,2.php,3.php">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" class='search'/>
<Input type="image" src=""  value="Search" class="search_button" /><br />
</form>
```

I want to set a search box and post a value to 3 pages. The 3 pages get the values and run themselves, after a process,

- 1.php generate 1.jpg,
- 2.php generate 2.jpg,
- 3.php generate 3.jpg.
- Then index.php waiting 3 images generated, then make a echo, show the
  3 images.

How to do that? thanks.

Comment: Do you have to post the input to the scripts, or could you use GET? Also, which method better matches the intent of your action? That is, are you getting a resource, or putting data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To ? Form Post to Multiple Locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585307/how-to-form-post-to-multiple-locations)

Comment: @xcsape - he's only been a user for 6 days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use standard HTML forms to send requests to three different pages in this way. A form is designed to send an HTTP request to only one location.

Ideally, you would have a single `target.php` file which then calls files `1.php` `2.php` and `3.php` on the server through `include`, merges the results, and sends them back to the user.

Failing that (for instance, some of the files are on different servers), you could use redirection: `1.php` redirects to `2.php` when it's done, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You could try reloading your page with

```
<img src="1.php?search=foo" alt="" />
<img src="2.php?search=foo" alt="" />
<img src="3.php?search=foo" alt="" />
```

To do this you could write index.php like this

> ```
> <?php
> $search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';
> ?>
> <form action="" method="get">
>     <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class='search'/>
>     <input type="image" src=""  value="Search" class="search_button" /><br />
> </form>
> <?php
> if($search !== '') {
> ?>
>     <img src="1.php?search=<?php echo $search; ?>" alt="" />
>     <img src="2.php?search=<?php echo $search; ?>" alt="" />
>     <img src="3.php?search=<?php echo $search; ?>" alt="" />
>
> <?php
> }
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure I follow what you are trying to do here- if each of the three pages outputs an image, why not go straight to the final page and have three `<img ../>` tags - each one with the `src` of the appropriate php script which outputs the image.

So simply direct to index.php, and index.php includes:

```
<img src='<?php echo "image1generator.php";?>' alt='' />
<img src='<?php echo "image2generator.php";?>' alt='' />
<img src='<?php echo "image3generator.php";?>' alt='' />
```

This will be on the bases that the imagexgenerator.php scripts output an actual image (with appropriate headers), if not...just use a series of '[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)' statements.

Answer (score 0):

Make "page.php" and include the files like:

```
include "image1.php";
include "image2.php";
include "image3.php";
```

But don't forget to store the images instead of outputting them.

You also could put the values in an $_SESSION, and use something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo "image1.php";?>" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo "image2.php";?>" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo "image3.php";?>" alt="" />
```