# How to integrate newsletter subcription using Campaign Monitor?

Tags: php, yii, newsletter

I've implemented a newsletter subscribe option in my website. Currently it was invented as when a user enter the email address it saved to our own database.

I would like to know is it possible to send that email address to my campaignmonitor.com account? I would expect maintanance will be less. I saw some Drupal and other CMS software has this option but, since my site is in Yii framework, I'm not sure how?

Can anyone please clarify how can I do this upgrade?

Comment: Yep, use the API: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/. You can access this via JSON using something like [Pest](https://github.com/educoder/pest).

Comment: Can you please let me know In terms of API is there way to install the campaignmonitor newsletter. Becase I found the following site has the campaign monitor newsletter subscriber form http://www.creativedeuce.co.uk/. When I inspect newsletter subscriber form element it's pretty clean and they may have installed very easily. Could you please let me know how this is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

In your Campaign Monitor account

1. Go to your **Lists & Subscribers tab** and select your subscriber Clist
2. Click **Grow your audience** link in the right panel

There are a few options there on how to sign up subscribers. If you choose **copy/paste a form to your site**, it will generate the form code for you to place on your website.

If you want to post the form input to BOTH Campaign Monitor and your database at the same time, [this thread might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585307/how-to-form-post-to-multiple-locations)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, yes it is possible. There may be an easy way to do this, via embedding a form that POSTs to a Campaign Monitor URL. However, since I've never used CM, I can't say for sure - do look at their website.

The way I would do it is to add some PHP to your website to handle the subscription using their REST API. So, download [Pest](https://github.com/educoder/pest) (or some other REST client) and install it in your codebase. I chose this one for my own work as it works with 5.2, but there's some fancier ones if you are on 5.3 or above.

Then, create an API key using the CM website. Using this, you can use a POST form to submit an email address to your site, at which point you can use the API to add the address to your subscriber database. I don't know if that triggers an opt-in email on the CM side; if it does not, then you should do that yourself.

This isn't a completely trivial programming problem, but give it a go, and have a good study of the CM technical documentation - it looks pretty thorough. Also, there are examples in the Pest README on how to call a RESTful API.