# redirect GET data to another site with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a form on the front end. I use jQuery to collect and send the data to collect.php.

I want collect.php to send the to another site in the following format **?fname=tom&phone=3434343** .

How do I simply send the data that is sent to collect.php to this other site?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have already collected data and sent it to `collect.php`, you probably will have to do something like this:

```
$query = http_build_query( $_GET );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/something.php?" . $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This will let send the data to another site from your PHP script.

If you also need to provide an user agent string or refer (as in - fake a browser), then you should look in to options provided by [`curl_setopt()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

The alternative solution would be to use [sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), but that would need you to explore HTTP protocol itself.

Comment: ... I wonder, why I got a downvote? Not enough jQuery?

Comment: This is the correct answer as he specifically sates that he wants to forward the request from collect.php to another website. The answers that just redirect the form with jquery or html are not helpful at all.

Comment: And what if `$_GET` contain `UNICODE` chars? Then that chars should properly be `url_decode()`d. Also why not to use built-in function `http_build_query()`? like `$query = http_build_query(array('foo' => 'bar'))`?

Comment: @DaveJust  because I was confusing it with `http_build_url()`, edited 2 seconds after you posted that. And the idea was just to provide a direction, not spoon-feed the complete answer. Where's fun in that!

Answer (score 0):

use `get` method for generating query string i.e `?fname=tom&phone=3434343 .`

Set `action` to the site url you want the form to get submit

```
<form action="URL" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

also Read http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

**Update**

[How To ? Form Post to Multiple Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585307/how-to-form-post-to-multiple-locations)

> The best way to go about it would be to first submit the form to your
>   local script, then use CURL to POST the (filtered) data that was
>   received to the remote script. Then just watch for the response.
>
> Then simply send the email and process the response from the remote
>   script in your local one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it in an invisible way via PHP, you might use CURL extension (usually already integrated), you have a tutorial here : http://www.binarytides.com/php-curl-tutorial-beginners

Answer (score -1):

I understand your question like you had send the data in a form on your collect.php then you want again to send the data from collect.php to another page `e.g anotherpage.php`. Correct me if that is not what you want to do.

If so, why not use again jquery in your collect.php

```
$.get('anotherpage.php', { fname: 'tom', phone: '3434343' });
```

Hope it helps.....

Comment: You are not redirecting to another page by $.get

Comment: @davidkonrad he did not say you have to redirect to another page, just simply send the data. My idea must not be vote down because I am only answering what was ask\