# Send Same HTML form on two different domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

Might be someone already asked this question.. but unable to find an answer yet..

I got a form  with following action

```
<form action="http://processing.com/formaction.php" method="get" id="form1">
```

Can some body tell me, how can I send a single form on two different domains ??

- I want form to be sent to `tracking.com/action.php` , but dont want any
  response back from this
- I want form to be sent to `processing.com/formaction.php` and my form
  processing would come from  here

please guide me over this..

thanks

**P.S**

- I dont have any control over tracking.com or processing.com
- Basically, `tracking.com` will track down my form..
- `procssing.com` is search site which will show the result of my form

Comment: [See this question : Form Post to Multiple Locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585307/how-to-form-post-to-multiple-locations).

Answer (score 0):

You could submit to the tracking page with ajax, and when this is done, actually send it to processing :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#form1').submit(function(event){

        // Do not send it yet
        event.preventDefault();
        // Track    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                name : $('#name').val(), // Gather all your fields here
                email: $('#email').val() // (nameOfField: value)
            },
            url: 'http://tracking.com/page.php',
            success: function(data){
                // Form submitted to tracking, now send it to processing
                $('#form1').submit();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('There was an error while tracking!');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: erorr is poping...with 'data: 'awinmid=4014&awinaffid=205895&p=http://www.book.xyz.com/search.do','

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resourc

Comment: That's because the server does not accept ajax requests from your domain... If you don't have access to their server, I have no solution for you, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set the target of the form to an iframe and then submit again. The solution is taken from this page: [how to create multi-submit form](http://www.html-form-guide.com/web-form/submit-form-multiple-scripts.html)

> ```
> <input type='button' name='Submit' value='Submit' onclick='javascript: return SubmitForm()' />
>
> function SubmitForm()
> {
>      document.forms['contactus'].action='tracking.com/action.php';
>      document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result1';
>      document.forms['contactus'].submit();
>
>      document.forms['contactus'].action='processing.com/formaction.php';
>      document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result2';
>      document.forms['contactus'].submit();
>      return true;
> }
> ```

You can hide the result iframes or redirect from the second iframe.